# Tiny MCE editor line breaks (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I would like change the default Tiny MCE post editor settings in WordPress.

I use Classic Editor 1.6.2 WP plugin.

WordPress: 5.8.2.

My problem:

All `<br>` and `<p>` tags deleted, when I click the "Visual" tab from "Text" tab and then back.

I need these HTML line break tags and not need the replaced line breaks.

How to?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Tiny apparently one that no one has any intention of fixing. Their response is that these tags are removed but that the breaks remain, which is untrue once you start editing the text anywhere else in the "text" editor view. It makes no sense that they would keep all other tags but then remove only those, but sadly, this is how this has been working, and there's no indication of anyone wanting to fix it.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the known issue?